# Make RadiobButton Dynamically in Listview Builder in but select one button at a time in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I used this code but select all buttons like a checkbox

```
ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                              itemCount: sampleData.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ButtonBar(
                                alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Radio(
                                    groupValue: groupValue[index],
                                    value: value[index][0],
                                    onChanged: (newValue) => setState(() => groupValue[index] = newValue as int),
                                  ),
                                  
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
```

Please correct me where I am wrong

[image]

I want to create like this with dynamically and one selection at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a Model class like tis;

```
class ItemModel {
  final String title;
  final int value;
  ItemModel({required this.title, required this.value});
}
```

then create a list like this:

```
List<ItemModel> _testList = [
    ItemModel(title: 'test1', value: 0),
    ItemModel(title: 'test2', value: 1),
    ItemModel(title: 'test3', value: 2),
  ];

  var groupValue = -1;
```

then use this:

```
ListView.builder(
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: _testList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
            child: ButtonBar(
              alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              buttonPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(_testList[index].title),
                Radio(
                  groupValue: groupValue,
                  value: _testList[index].value,
                  onChanged: (newValue) =>
                      setState(() => groupValue = newValue as int),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
```

[image]

Comment: how to remove spacing between buttons

Comment: @MohammedFaizan Is that what you looking for?

Comment: m looking for solution of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73657240/radio-button-change-when-select-next-radio-button-in-listview-flutter

Comment: I don't have good felling about helping you. you are not appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, I m a little bit busy with my code problems, I m new to a flutter.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, You have used a stateful widget for each button.
after that, you have defined a boolean variable in that class.
finally, you have called a setState when u press on it.
something like this:

```
ListView.builder(
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: _testList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Test()
        );
```

second class:

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  bool active = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Checkbox(
            value: active,
            onChanged: (v) {
              setState(() {
                active = v!;
              });
            }),
            Text("text")
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't understand, I can explain that in Persian.